# Undefined variable: header (View: C:\blog\resources\views\pages\welcome.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-5

I am getting the below error when running application,

```
Undefined variable: header (View: C:\blog\resources\views\pages\welcome.blade.php)
```

My getIndex() function in Controller:

```
public function getIndex(){
        \View::make('pages/welcome')->nest('header', 'layout.header');
        return view('pages/welcome');
    }
```

My welcome.blade.php

```
{{ $header }}
<body>
....
</body>
```

My _partial/header.blade.php,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Blog Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

After following the answer, the html looks like,

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
    &lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt;
    &lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no&quot;&gt;
    &lt;meta name=&quot;description&quot; content=&quot;&quot;&gt;
    &lt;meta name=&quot;author&quot; content=&quot;&quot;&gt;
    &lt;link rel=&quot;icon&quot; href=&quot;../../favicon.ico&quot;&gt;

    &lt;title&gt;Blog Template for Bootstrap&lt;/title&gt;

    &lt;!-- Bootstrap core CSS --&gt;
    &lt;link href=&quot;https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css&quot; rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot;&gt;

    &lt;!-- Custom styles for this template --&gt;
    &lt;link href=&quot;http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/style.css&quot; rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot;&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a view with a nested subview, then creating & returning a *totally new view* without the nested subview instead:

```
public function getIndex(){
    \View::make('pages/welcome')->nest('header', 'layout.header');
    return view('pages/welcome');
}
```

Should be

```
public function getIndex(){
    return \View::make('pages/welcome')->nest('header', 'layout.header');
}
```

Note that `view()` is an alias of `\View::make()`.

You can prevent the HTML from being escaped by using `{!! $header !!}` instead.

With Laravel 5+ development, you should be using [Components and Slots](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#components-and-slots) to inject templates into your views instead.

Comment: Try `{!! $header !!}` - this does not escape data.

Comment: Now it says, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting ',' or ')'"

Comment: Edited - one curly brace on each side - not 2.

Comment: Can you also share how to return more than one sections?